# Import custom prediction routine to vertex AI pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines, vertex-ai-pipeline

I have created a [custom prediction routine](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-prediction-routines) on Vertex AI, uploaded the model, and am able to generate predictions with it through the UI. Now, I would like to incorporate this into a Vertex AI Pipeline, to run batch predictions after a data generation step. I am using the Kubeflow Pipelines SDK.

To do so, I am thinking of using the [`ModelBatchPredictOp`](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-2.8.0/api/v1/batch_predict_job.html#v1.batch_predict_job.ModelBatchPredictOp) prebuilt component. For this to work, I need to import the model into the pipeline, for example with an [importer component](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/components/importer-component/). HOWEVER, the importer component requires an artifact URI, which my model does not have because it uses a custom container. It is baked into the container image; it is not sitting in GCS.

So I tried, though I did not really expect it to work, writing a quick custom importer component, which returns the model object, but I get a type mismatch. See sample code below:

```
from helper import data_component
from kfp.dsl import component, pipeline, Output, Model
from google_cloud_pipeline_components.v1.batch_predict_job import ModelBatchPredictOp


@component(packages_to_install=["google-cloud-aiplatform"])
def custom_importer(model: Output[Model]):
    from google.cloud import aiplatform
    return aiplatform.Model(model_name="model-id")


@pipeline(name="prediction-pipeline")
def pipeline():
    data_task = data_component()
    
    importer_task = custom_importer()

    batch_predict_op = ModelBatchPredictOp(
        job_display_name="batch_predict_job",
        model=importer_task.output,
        gcs_source_uris=data_task.outputs["dataset"],
        gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix="bucket",
        instances_format="csv",
        predictions_format="jsonl",
        starting_replica_count=1,
        max_replica_count=1,
    )
```

The `ModelBatchPredictOp` doesn't like the input type for arg `model`: `InconsistentTypeException: Incompatible argument passed to the input 'model' of component 'model-batch-predict': Argument type 'system.Model@0.0.1' is incompatible with the input type 'google.VertexModel@0.0.1'`

How can I incorporate batch prediction from a custom prediction routine into a Vertex AI Pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is in the Model Registry, I think you should use [ModelGetOp](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-2.9.0/api/v1/model.html#v1.model.ModelGetOp) operator.

```
v1.model.ModelGetOp(
    model_name: str, 
    project: str = '{{$.pipeline_google_cloud_project_id}}', 
    location: str = 'us-central1')¶
```

You will need to enter the model resource name in the model_name argument. You can get it programmatically like this:

```
model_name = 'my_model'
model_resource_name = aiplatform.Model.list(filter=f'display_name="{model_name}"')[0].resource_name
```

You can use GetVertexModelOp if you're using earlier versions of google-cloud-pipeline-components/kfp.